# Why isn't my discord bot stop replying even after adding a break statement [python]

Tags: python

```
import hikari

bot = hikari.GatewayBot(token='OTY1OTU2NTYzNzgzMjc4NTky.Yl6vJw.ESrN-xKdob4Bar80k0sgmS8JjJs')


@bot.listen()
async def ping(event: hikari.GuildMessageCreateEvent) -> None:
    if event.is_bot or not event.content:
        return

    if event.content.startswith('!hi'):
        i = 1
        if i == 1:
            while True:
                await event.message.respond('Hello')
                await event.message.respond(i)
                if i == 1:
                    await event.message.respond('Hello')
                    await event.message.respond(i)
                else:
                    break
    if event.content.startswith('!stop'):
        i = 0

bot.run()
```

I added a while loops statement so the bot could keeping messaging until the user command it to stop. But even after adding a break statement it isn't stopping. I just want to stop  the while loop and not logout the bot. what is causing this problem?

Comment: `i` never changes during the while loop.  It is always equal to 1, so the `else` never happens.

Comment: @JohnGordon so the `!stop` isn't working? how can I change the value of `i` ?

Comment: Your bot is still in the while loop so it can't read new commands sent to it. This means i is never set to 0 and it runs indefinately

Comment: The way you have it set up, the `!stop` can't possibly work the way you want.

Comment: @Haisi so is there any way better way for it do keeping messaging while receiving other commands?

Answer (score 0):

You want to the loop to cancel if the "!stop" is read right? So just have your code say that by including the stop event in your while loop.

```
if event.content.startswith('!hi'):
            while True:
                await event.message.respond('Hello')
                await event.message.respond(i)
                if event.content.startswith('!stop'):
                   break
```

Really want to use a variable i and math? You would need to structure your while loop differently.

```
    while i < 1:
       *Do the thing*
       if *someone wants it to stop*:
           i += 1
```

Here's a link to a video and a guide about while loops in python.  This guy helped me every step of the way as I stumbled my way through python.

https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/python-programming/beginner-python-tutorials/while-loops/

If you like the video or guide I'm sure he'll have something about Discord.